# prompt window submits form no matter the if else check

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, twig

I have integrated confirmation window to my Symfony form with javascript function.

This is my start form definition:

```
{{ form_start(form, {'attr': {'role': 'form', 'id':'editForm'} } ) }}
```

And in javascript:

```
$('#editForm').on('submit', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
validateEditForm();
});

function validateEditForm()
{
    var nameInput;
    nameInput = prompt('Please input name to confirm edit:');
    var name = document.getElementById('edit_name').value;

if (nameInput === name || Number(nameInput) === name) {
    $('#editForm').submit();
} else if (nameInput === null || nameInput === "") {
    alert('You must enter name to confirm!');
    return false;
} else {
    alert("Entered name and default name don't match!");
    return false;
}
```

One case is not working.

When I enter correct name in the box then *Please input workspace name to confirm edit:* appears again. Then I click **OK** again and the form is submitted.. Is there something wrong with my if else checks?

*Edit:* Tried to do it in two separate functions and used     `e.preventDefault();` and the behaviour was the same.

Comment: You did not make the prompt dependent on _any_ conditions, so of course it shows up every single time you call validateEditForm.

Comment: Can someone please elaborate this? I am new at writing JavaScript code so do not know what is that I did wrong. Thanks @CBroe

Comment: No, I can't elaborate, because right now, I can't even tell what exactly you actually want to achieve here.

Comment: I want to submit form if the name that user inputed in prompt box is the same as the name value filed in the form or alert otherwise. @CBroe

Comment: So you want it to prompt the user only when they try to submit the form for the first time? And then, on subsequent attempts, you want to not ask again, but keep using the name they already entered previously? Then take `var nameInput;` out of the function, and make it a global variable instead. And then inside the function, just check if `nameInput` already contains anything - and only if it doesn't, you actually call the `prompt` method.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Is this even related to PHP, Symfony, or Twig if you are solely using Javascript for this process?

Answer (score 0):

I change validateEditForm method as returning boolean. On the form submit event, validateEditForm method decides whether submit the form  or not.

```js
$('#editForm').on('submit', function (e) {

    if(!validateEditForm()) {
         e.preventDefault();
    }
});

function validateEditForm()
{
    var nameInput;
    nameInput = prompt('Please input name to confirm edit:');
    var name = document.getElementById('edit_name').value;

if (nameInput === name || Number(nameInput) === name) {
    return true;
} else if (nameInput === null || nameInput === "") {
    alert('You must enter name to confirm!');
    return false;
} else {
    alert("Entered name and default name don't match!");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. What did you change, and why?